# how to modify app.manifest in order to publish an app what needs database permissions?

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, clickonce

I want to publish an xbap app but I can't get it due to a problem with ClickOnce.
My app needs to use an oracle database. If I publish it with enabled ClickOnce and 'this is a partial trust application' the publishing is OK, but the access to database doesn't work.

If I choose 'this is a full trust application' I can't publish.

I have tried to disable ClickOnce but the wizard enables it again.

Also, I have tried to custom and edit permissions XML and where it reads:

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

I have written:
        
But an exception is ocurred:
ClickOnce is not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'

Any help is useful for me.

The errors are:

> An exception occurred when determining confidence. We detected the
>   following error messages: User has declined to grant the required
>   permissions for the application.
>
> An exception occurred while downloading the application. We detected
>   the following error messages: AssertApplicationRequirements method
>   failed. The application can not be confirmed.

But I don't know what AssertApplicationRequirements is.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to publish the app as full-trust?

Comment: The errors you mention relate to the end-user installation of the app, not the publishing. Is that where your problem is?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the errors occurs when I click on publish. When the publish wizard ends it tries to launch the app but it can't due to the errors that I have written

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post on Connect](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/035c5b25-b209-45e3-ba1c-e667a765bb31) you have to use [caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz.aspx) to fix this:

```
From the computer that you are trying to run the XBAP application on, 
can you run the following command (you can run it from the Run Dialog,
or a command prompt):

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol -m -ag 1 -url 
          "http://localhost/xbaptest/clickonce*" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run it, I have to specify my iis project path   instead of "/xbaptest/clickonce*" ? I have tried to run it but I can't. The parameter '-ag 1' isn't recognized. What is the objective of this command? What does it do?